# Load JSON DATA From GITHUB IN PYTHON AND STREMLIT

Tags: python, json, streamlit

Hi to all and thanks in advance for your help,

I´ve developing with streamlit and Python and now I would like to deploy all the thinks in Heroku.

It´s my first time deploying an app in heroku. I **want to load json files form github** becouse I would like to have the app weekly updated with the statsbomb data.

**Until now I have been loading the json files from my computer,** please find attached the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
from pandas import json_normalize
from flatten_json import flatten

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import urllib, json

### NAME OF THE APP ###
x = st.sidebar.header(' Analytics')  #  this is a widget

### SEASON SELECTOR ###
file_to_charge2 = st.sidebar.selectbox('temporada',('Temporada 2018-2019','Temporada 2017-2018','Temporada 2016-2017'))

if file_to_charge2 == 'Temporada 2018-2019':
    file_to_charge = '4.json'
elif file_to_charge2 == 'Temporada 2017-2018':
    file_to_charge2 = '1.json'
elif file_to_charge2== 'Temporada 2016-2017':
    file_to_charge = '2.json'


### MATCH SELECTOR ###

home_team = st.sidebar.selectbox('Equipo juega en casa:',('Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta Vigo', 'Deportivo Alavés', 'Deportivo La Coruna', 'Eibar', 'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Granada', 'Las Palmas', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Málaga', 'Osasuna', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Sporting Gijón', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'))
away_team = st.sidebar.selectbox('Equipo fuera de casa:',('Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta Vigo', 'Deportivo Alavés', 'Deportivo La Coruna', 'Eibar', 'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Granada', 'Las Palmas', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Málaga', 'Osasuna', 'Rayo Vallecano', 'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Sporting Gijón', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'))
#json_normalize(my_data3, sep='_').assign(match_id=file_name[:-5])



###LOAD THE JSON FILE FROM COMPUTER### 

st.title('> Datos por temporada:')
dfpartidos = json.load(open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/DATOS/open-data-master/data/matches/11/' + file_to_charge), 'r', encoding='utf-8'))



### DATAFRAME OF THE SEASON ###
FIELDS = ['match_id','match_week',"home_team.home_team_name",'away_team.away_team_name','home_score','away_score','referee.name']
dfdef = pd.json_normalize(dfpartidos)
p = dfdef[FIELDS]

### DATAFRAME OF THE TEAMS ###
l = p.loc[p['home_team.home_team_name'] == home_team, :]
l = l.loc[l['away_team.away_team_name'] == away_team, :]




#TABLE WITH DATA OF THE SELECTED SEASON:
st.subheader('Datos de la  {} :'.format(file_to_charge2))
st.write(p)

#TABLE WITH DATA OF THE SELECETED TEAMS

st.write('Home Team:',home_team,'VS','Away Team:',away_team)

st.write(l)
```

This code works well and it's ready to analayze amazing data. But **If I want to have an updated app. And that is the reason why I need to launch the json files form github**. I have done some unsuccesfull tests but I have some issues. Please find attached the code and the error.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
from pandas import json_normalize
from flatten_json import flatten

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import urllib, json
import plotly.express as px
import altair as atl
import re, json, requests

x = st.sidebar.header(' Analytics')  #  this is a widget

####
file_to_charge2 = st.sidebar.selectbox('temporada',
                                       ('Temporada 2018-2019', 'Temporada 2017-2018', 'Temporada 2016-2017'))

if file_to_charge2 == 'Temporada 2018-2019':
    file_to_charge = '4.json'
elif file_to_charge2 == 'Temporada 2017-2018':
    file_to_charge2 = '1.json'
elif file_to_charge2 == 'Temporada 2016-2017':
    file_to_charge = '2.json'


### busqueda de partidos ###

home_team = st.sidebar.selectbox('Equipo juega en casa:', (
'Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta Vigo', 'Deportivo Alavés', 'Deportivo La Coruna', 'Eibar',
'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Granada', 'Las Palmas', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Málaga', 'Osasuna', 'Rayo Vallecano',
'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Sporting Gijón', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'))
away_team = st.sidebar.selectbox('Equipo fuera de casa:', (
'Athletic Bilbao', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Celta Vigo', 'Deportivo Alavés', 'Deportivo La Coruna', 'Eibar',
'Espanyol', 'Getafe', 'Girona', 'Granada', 'Las Palmas', 'Leganés', 'Levante', 'Málaga', 'Osasuna', 'Rayo Vallecano',
'Real Betis', 'Real Madrid', 'Real Sociedad', 'Real Valladolid', 'Sevilla', 'Sporting Gijón', 'Valencia', 'Villarreal'))
# json_normalize(my_data3, sep='_').assign(match_id=file_name[:-5])




### TRYING TO LOAD DATA FROM GITHUB // THE PROBLEM ###
url = 'https://raw.github.com/statsbomb/open-data/matches/11/' + file_to_charge
resp = requests.get(url)
st.title('> Datos por temporada:')
dfpartidos = json.loads(resp.text)



### DATAFRAME OF THE SEASON ###
FIELDS = ['match_id', 'match_week', "home_team.home_team_name", 'away_team.away_team_name', 'home_score', 'away_score',
          'referee.name']
dfdef = pd.json_normalize(dfpartidos)
p = dfdef[FIELDS]

# DATAFRAME SEGÚN EQUIPOS FILTRADOS
l = p.loc[p['home_team.home_team_name'] == home_team, :]
l = l.loc[l['away_team.away_team_name'] == away_team, :]

# TABLE WITH DATA OF THE SELECTED SEASON:
st.subheader('Datos de la  {} :'.format(file_to_charge2))
st.write(p)

# TABLE WITH DATA OF THE SELECETED TEAMS

st.write('Home Team:', home_team, 'VS', 'Away Team:', away_team)

st.write(l)
```

**And the error loading json date from github.**

```
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
Traceback:
File "/Users/DOMIN2662/Desktop/streamlit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/DOMIN2662/Desktop/streamlit/duda22.py", line 50, in <module>
    dfpartidos = json.loads(resp.text)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

I want to highlight the support of comunity and I hope that in the next future I can help others  developers.

Comment: TLDR: what is your question?

Comment: I can not load json files from github, and I need it  (2º Code) and the 3º Code  is the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing at the wrong URL, which will return a 404 instead of valid JSON. That in turn cannot be parsed by `json.loads`, leading to the `JSONDecodeError`

Change your `url` variable code to:

```
url = (
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/statsbomb/open-data/master/data/matches/11/"
+ file_to_charge
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try and i will say to you. Thanks again